# FCM - Flutter tap on notification to open app (all states)

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app which subscribes to a topic in Firebase Messaging. (for example the topic is "test").

and with cloud functions I successfully send a notification to all devices subscribed to the "test" topic.

I need when the user taps on the notification to open the app in the main screen.

this is my cloud function:

```
  .document('testdocument/{testdc}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic('test', {
      notification: {
        title: "APP MON",
        body: "Check Mon!!!",
        clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
      },
    });
  });
```

am I missing something?

P.S: The notifications show fine (with the Icon of my app and the message I need, they just don't do anything) - also, this is needed only for ANDROID

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The correct parameter is [`click_action`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messagings/latest/#:%7E:text=to%20set%20the-,click_action,-property%20of%20the).